# How do save android file path in java?

Tags: android

I've seen a lot of android application enable to save file and resume it for future. How to do it in Java? Which location should I pointing to on android OS?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: You should read this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html It shows how to save file and where the files can be saved.

Comment: Are you talking about downloading a file? Or just saving application data to a file? For downloading a file, you want the DownloadManager.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan I want to create a application for android OS. I'm wondering how to save the data in java perspective.